# Spree Commerce: changing the header only for the checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I would like to change the header and footer and other things of the base template only for the checkout page.

Is this possible with deface?

I would like to use a deface block like this:

```
Deface::Override.new( :virtual_path   => 'spree/layouts/spree_application',
                      :name           => 'logo_checkout',
                      :replace_contents => '#logo',
                      :text        => 'You are in the checkout')
```

But this deface rule should only work when a user is in the checkout, for example on page:

```
/checkout/registration
```

Is there any way to do this with deface? And if not, how could I make changes to the base template for only a specific group of pages?

Answer (score 0):

Rein,

instead of specifying text, specify a partial.

In that partial, you can check your controller or url or whatever to render different content based on whatever rules you specify, just like you would in a normal view.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking about this to but liked to do it with Deface. But this is a way.

Comment: But the <% if current_page?('checkout') %> won't return true in checkout, don't get the paths yet. Any idea about that?